# How can I handle micros() double rollover?

Tags: time

I know that I can handle a single rollover with subtraction:

```
if (micros() - lastTime > period) {
  lastTime = micros();
  ...
}
```

But how it can be handled if this is not `true` or it is not checked for more than 70 minutes (without using uint64_t)?

Comment: What is the objection to using `millis()` if you are timing rather long periods?

Comment: I'm using my implementation of micros() and I don't want to implement millis() because it makes the ISR bigger. Also the precision.

Comment: So just to be clear, this is **your** version of micros you are asking us about? How about posting the code to it?

Comment: It's the same as Arduino's version except that in `ISR(TIMER0_OVF_vect)` there is a single variable increment. The code needs to run with as little interruptions as possible and I want to be able to run something with irregular long intervals.

Comment: It's the same as the Arduino version, except it's completely different, is that it? I gather this is top-secret code.

Comment: It is the same, and it has nothing to do with the question: `
#define clockCyclesPerMicrosecond() ( F_CPU / 1000000L )
volatile uint32_t timer0OverflowCount = 0;

ISR(TIMER0_OVF_vect) {
  ++timer0OverflowCount;
}

uint32_t us() {
  uint32_t m;
  uint8_t t;
  uint8_t oldSREG = SREG;
  cli();
  m = timer0OverflowCount;
  t = TCNT0;
  if (((TIFR0 & (1 << TOV0)) && (t < 255))) ++m;
  SREG = oldSREG;
  return ((m << 8) + t) * (64 / clockCyclesPerMicrosecond());
} `

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Do you want `period` to be more than 70 minutes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to measure times longer than 70 minutes with
`micros()`, you *will have to* use `uint64_t`, and there is nothing
wrong with that.

> The code needs to run with as little interruptions as possible [...]

You don't need to do the 64-bit arithmetic within the ISR. You could
very well implement an interrupt-driven 32-bit version, and then extend
it to 64 bits in non-interrupt context. Example:

```c++
// Your ISR-based implementation.
uint32_t micros32();

// Extend to 64 bits.
uint64_t micros64() {
    static uint64_t time64;
    time64 += micros() - (uint32_t) time64;
    return time64;
}
```

This should work as long as you call `micros64()` often enough.
Presumably, you will have something like
`if (micros64() - lastTime > period) { ... }`
within your loop, so this should be no issue as long as you never block
your loop.

Actually, you can push this idea even further. If you can guarantee that
`micros64()` will be called at least once every 65.5 ms, then you
could have your ISR increment only a 16-bit counter.

Comment: Thank you, this will solve the issue. The last part will be a nice further optimization for my case.